# JSF : How to refresh required field in ajax request

Tags: ajax, jsf, richfaces

Ok, here you are the core problem.

The page. I have two required "input text". 
A command button that changes the bean value and reRenderes the "job" object.

```
<a4j:form id="pervForm">  
    SURNAME:<h:inputText id="surname" label="Surname" value="#{prevManager.surname}" required="true" />  
    <br/>               
    JOB:<h:inputText  value="#{prevManager.job}"  id="job"  maxlength="10" size="10"  label="#{msg.common_label_job}" required="true" />  
    <br/>  

    <a4j:commandButton value="Set job to Programmer" ajaxSingle="true" reRender="job">  
        <a4j:actionparam name="jVal" value="Programmer" assignTo="#{prevManager.job}"/>  
    </a4j:commandButton>  

    <h:commandButton id="save" value="save"  action="save" class="HATSBUTTON"/>  

</a4j:form>
```

Here the simple manager:

```
public class PrevManager   
{  

    private String surname;  
    private String job;  

    public String getSurname()  
    {  
        return surname;  
    }  

    public void setSurname(String surname)  
    {  
        this.surname = surname;  
    }  

    public String getJob()  
    {  
        return job;  
    }  

    public void setJob(String job)  
    {  
        this.job = job;  
    }  

    public String save()  
    {  
        //do something  
    }  

}
```

Let's do this:

Write something on the Job input text (such as "teacher"). 
Leave empty the surname. 
Save. 
Validation error appears (surname is mandatory). 
Press "Set job to Programmer": nothing happens.

Checking the bean value, I discovered that it is correctly updated, indeed the component on the page is not updated!

Well, according to the JBoss Docs I found:

> Ajax region is a key ajax component.
>   It limits the part of the component
>   tree to be processed on the server
>   side when ajax request comes.
>   Processing means invocation during
>   Decode, Validation and Model Update
>   phase. Most common reasons to use a
>   region are:
>
> -avoiding the aborting of the JSF lifecycle processing during the
>   validation of other form input
>   unnecessary for given ajax request; 
>   -defining the different strategies when events will be delivered
>   (immediate="true/false") 
>   -showing an individual indicator of an ajax status 
>   -increasing the performance of the rendering processing
>   (selfRendered="true/false",
>   renderRegionOnly="true/false")
>
> The following two examples show the
>   situation when a validation error does
>   not allow to process an ajax input.
>   Type the name. The outputText
>   component should reappear after you.
>   However, in the first case, this
>   activity will be aborted because of
>   the other field with required="true".
>   You will see only the error message
>   while the "Job" field is empty.

Here you are the example:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"  
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"  
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"  
      xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"  
      xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">  

        <style>  
            .outergridvalidationcolumn {  
                padding: 0px 30px 10px 0px;  
            }  
        </style>  

    <a4j:outputPanel ajaxRendered="true">  
        <h:messages style="color:red" />  
    </a4j:outputPanel>  
    <h:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="outergridvalidationcolumn">  

        <h:form id="form1">  
                <h:panelGrid columns="2">  
                    <h:outputText value="Name" />  
                    <h:inputText value="#{userBean.name}">  
                        <a4j:support event="onkeyup" reRender="outname" />  
                    </h:inputText>  
                    <h:outputText value="Job" />  
                    <h:inputText  required="true" id="job2" value="#{userBean.job}" />  
                </h:panelGrid>  
        </h:form>  

        <h:form id="form2">  
            <h:panelGrid columns="2">  
                <h:outputText value="Name" />  
                <a4j:region>  
                    <h:inputText value="#{userBean.name}">  
                        <a4j:support event="onkeyup" reRender="outname" />  
                    </h:inputText>  
                </a4j:region>  
                <h:outputText value="Job" />  
                <h:inputText   required="true"  id="job1"  value="#{userBean.job}" />  
            </h:panelGrid>  
        </h:form>  

    </h:panelGrid>  
    <h:outputText id="outname" style="font-weight:bold" value="Typed Name: #{userBean.name}" />  
    <br />  
</ui:composition>
```

Form1: the behaviour is incorrect. I need to fill the job and then the name. 
Form2: the behaviour is correct. I do not need to fill the job to see the correct value.

Unfortunately using Ajax region does not help (indeed I used it in a bad way ...) because my fields are both REQUIRED. That's the main different.

Any idea?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This problem is also identified in JSF 2 and explained in detail in this related answer: [How can I populate a text field using PrimeFaces AJAX after validation errors occur?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6642242/how-can-i-populate-a-text-field-using-primefaces-ajax-after-validation-errors-oc/6845800#6845800)

Summarized, the answer is that you need to clear the state of the [`EditableValueHolder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/faces/component/EditableValueHolder.html) component when it's about to be ajax-rendered, but which isn't included in the ajax-execute, by calling the methods [`setValue(null)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/faces/component/ValueHolder.html#setValue%28java.lang.Object%29), [`setSubmittedValue(null)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/faces/component/EditableValueHolder.html#setSubmittedValue%28java.lang.Object%29), [`setLocalValueSet(false)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/faces/component/EditableValueHolder.html#setLocalValueSet%28boolean%29), [`setValid(true)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/faces/component/EditableValueHolder.html#setValid%28boolean%29). Note: in JSF 2 you would have used the convenience method [`resetValue()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/EditableValueHolder.html#resetValue%28%29) instead.

Given that your "job" input field has the client ID `prevForm:job`, here's how you could clear it inside the action listener method associated with the "Set job to programmer" button:

```
UIInput input = (UIInput) context.getViewRoot().findComponent("prevForm:job");
input.setValue(null);
input.setSubmittedValue(null);
input.setLocalValueSet(false);
input.setValid(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a4j:actionparam will set the value, but will not help you bypass validation in this case. Validation happens on the component (not the bean property). So, when you submit, the component value is still empty. Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm not working on the invalid component. I only need to change the value of a valid component... I change the bean value and I cannot force the update (immediate, reRender, ajaxRegion and so no fail). The only way I found is by using process property. In this case the component is correctly updated but If and Only If it has an initial value (I mean: the component has a not null value). So, there is no way to force ...

Comment: Put ajaxSingle="true" on the button and then re-render the input component.

Comment: I've just tried but it does not work properly. It works fine until I submit the form and I trigger a validation error of a component on the page. At this point the button updates only the backing bean and not the field on the page. Indeed, if the component with validation problem is the one designed to be updated by the ajax call, IT WORKS. But if ANY other component is invalid, the ajax button can update only the backing bean and not the component. Maybe after the submit something happens that block the update. Losing my head, sorry.

Comment: I guess I'm just not sure what you are trying to achieve. Make sure you understand how JSF life cycle works and this article could also help: http://mkblog.exadel.com/2009/07/richfaces-region-partial-jsf-tree-processing/

Answer (score 0):

When you click "Set job to Programmer" nothing happens because you are not reRendering your message component. If you do, you'll be able to see the validation message.

You need to reRender the message because its a `<a4j:commandButton/>`, not a simple `<h:commandButton/>`

Try to use the prop. `immediate` in "Set job to Programmer" button and check if it will update the field.

```
<a4j:commandButton value="Set job to Programmer" ajaxSingle="true" reRender="job" immediate="true">
    <a4j:actionparam name="jVal" value="Programmer" assignTo="#{prevManager.job}"/>  
</a4j:commandButton>
```

*I dont think "ajaxSingle" necessary here..

Maybe you can get a new problem.. using `immediate`, the bean value will be not updated (MAYBE!). If it happens, make a bean method which sets manually the bean value.

Otherwise, if the bean value was updated and the field still empty, try to put the "job" field into a `<a4j:outputPanel/>` and reRender the outputPanel.

```
<a4j:outputPanel id="myPanel">
   <h:inputText  value="#{prevManager.job}"  id="job"  maxlength="10" size="10"  label="#{msg.common_label_job}" required="true" />
</a4j:outputPanel/>

<a4j:commandButton value="Set job to Programmer" reRender="myPanel" immediate="true">
    <a4j:actionparam name="jVal" value="Programmer" assignTo="#{prevManager.job}"/>  
</a4j:commandButton>
```

More info about `<a4j:outputPanel/>` [here](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/a4j_outputPanel.html).

Comment: I've just tried. Well, immediate="true" does not update the bean, as expected. It could be a solution, but the user may get lost: a validation error after submit will reset the field to the previous value.

Comment: Sorry if I did not understand your comment but immediate doesn't causes validation. Thats why I said, if it dont update the bean value, make a bean method to get the value and set manually to the class. With this, later on a form submit, the class will be loaded and the field will not be reseted, since the field will get the bean class value (value="#{prevManager.job}").