# JSF render is not working for form element

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a `composite` displayed inside a `dialog`. I have an `edit` button that get the current bean `@SessionScoped` (item in a data table) and then update the UI. My app is very similar to a simple CRUD app like http://balusc.blogspot.com/2010/06/benefits-and-pitfalls-of-viewscoped.html.

The problem is that the UI is updated correctly when using `<h:outputText/>` but not when using a form element.

```
<h:inputTextarea value="#{cc.attrs.managedBean.assertionStatement}" />
<h:inputText value="#{cc.attrs.managedBean.assertionStatement}" />
<h:outputText value="#{cc.attrs.managedBean.assertionStatement}"/>
```

The UI shows an empty `textarea` and `input` but the outputText renders the correct value. The `getAssertionStatement()` is called 3 times which seems to be the correct behavior.

When I close the dialog and reopen it, everything (form element) is populated.

The dialog call (`ag` namespace is for composite component):

```
    <p:dialog widgetVar="DataValueRuleDialog" modal="true" height="600" width="800">
        <p:outputPanel id="DataValueRulePanel">
            <ag:DataValueAssertion managedBean="#{dataValueAssertionController}" id="DataValueComposite" />
        </p:outputPanel>
    </p:dialog>
```

The composite that calls another composite:

```
    <h:form id="DataValueForm">
        <ag:assertionMetadataComponent
            managedBean="#{cc.attrs.managedBean.dataValueAssertionBean.assertionMetadataBean}"
            assertionStatementRows="5" />

        <p:dataTable value="#{cc.attrs.managedBean.model}" var="item">
            <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Assertion Statement</f:facet>
                <h:outputText rendered="#{item.profileBean.profileLocation == cc.attrs.managedBean.selectedComformanceProfile.name}" value="#{item.assertionMetadataBean.assertionStatement}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <p:commandButton rendered="#{item.profileBean.profileLocation == cc.attrs.managedBean.selectedComformanceProfile.name}" value="edit" immediate="true"
                actionListener="#{cc.attrs.managedBean.editDataValueAssertion}" update=":DataValueComposite:DataValueForm">
                </p:commandButton>
            </p:column> 
        </p:dataTable>
    </h:form>
```

When I remove the `immediate=true` the form is validated and since one of the required field (supposed to be populated) is missing, I got a validation error. This is why I have `immediate=true` but it should be necessary since all the items in the data table should be valid.

Comment: When you say "dialog", do you actually mean `<p:dialog>`? Further, it's hard to naildown the cause based on the as far provided information. You'll really have to show a bit more code than that. Show the smallest possible snippet of the `<h:form>` and the `<cc:implementation>` which exhibits the problem.

Comment: Updated my questions with code sample

Comment: I'm not sure, but since you're talking about refilling the fields by ajax  after validation errors, you might find this useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6642242/how-can-i-populate-a-text-field-using-primefaces-ajax-after-validation-errors-occ

Comment: Is #{item#} really an item (row) from a data table and session scoped? If so, that can only end in tears I'm afraid.

Comment: The link from `BalusC` seems to fix the problem.