# @NotEmpty List validation

Tags: jsf, arraylist, jsf-2, bean-validation, selectmanymenu

I have a JSF component which is mapped on a List in the corresponding bean.
As I want the mapped field to contain at least one value when the form is submitted, this field is annoted @NotEmpty.

**Bean :**

```
public class MyBean {

    @NotEmpty(message="Validation failed")
    private List<String> selectedOptions = new ArrayList<>();

    ... getter & setter

}
```

Each time the user select something on my component I want the selection to be immediatly mapped in the bean, so I add an ajax behaviour to the component (Here the component is a `p:selectManyMenu` but the issue seems to be present with any component mapped to a List) :

**XHTML :**

```
<h:form>
    <p:outputLabel for="optionslist" value="Options :" />
    <p:selectManyMenu id="optionslist" value="#{myBean.selectedOptions}" style="margin-bottom:50px">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option 1" itemValue="1" />
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option 2" itemValue="2" />
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option 3" itemValue="3" />
        <p:ajax process="@this" update="result optionsListMessage" /> 
    </p:selectManyMenu>

    <p:commandButton value="Submit" update="result optionsListMessage" />

    <p:message for="optionslist" id="optionsListMessage" />

    <p:dataList id="result" value="#{myBean.selectedOptions}" var="option">
        <h:outputText value="#{option}" />
    </p:dataList>
</h:form>
```

My issue happens in the following situation :

1. The user selects one or several choices (Ctrl + click here).
2. He unselects **every** choices he just selected.
3. He submits the form.
4. We can see in the result `dataList` that the last unselected value is still in the bean.

My understanding of the situation is that when the user unselects the last value, the validation fails because of the @NotEmpty annotation on the field (as confirmed by the `p:message` validation failure message). As a consequence the setter is not called and the last unselected value remains in the bean.

How can I, in a proper way, allow the user to unselect every items without validation failures, and run the validator on this field only when the form is submitted ?

Comment: i copy and past and it work for me. Can you try to refresh page. by Using Ctrl+F5.

Comment: @ankushyadav It works even when you deselect every choices and submit the form ?  

In my case the `datalist` will contain the last unselected value.

Comment: how did you check that your datalist have last unselected value. when i check is show size zero.

Comment: When I submit the form the datalist is updated with the current content of the selectedOptions field.

Comment: I think we are not in same page correct me if i am wrong. in last comment you want when user unselect the last choice from list, that time below datalist should not display any thing am i right?
I checked my code is working fine i am getting list size zero, when i submit the form. can you explain more about your problem and put more log, that can help. Thanks Ankushy

Comment: If you want to update your datalist on UI(VIEW), you can use 
<p:ajax process="@this" update="result"/> 
this will update the datalist.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the code with your suggestion and the update of a validation message on each action. I guess you're right, not sure we're  discussing about the same scenario ;)

Comment: If you select option 1 and then unselect it (Ctrl+click), do you have a "validation failed" message on the UI and is the selectedOptions setter called in the bean ?

Comment: yes, my setter method get call each time, when i select it call with one value in list, when unselect it call with zero value. validation take place only when you submit the form. and i am getting error message on UI, when i am submit the form. better to update your form on submit button.

Comment: It's weird, my setter is called each time except when I unselect the last option, which seems to be normal behaviour because of the validation failure. The behaviour you describe is the one I want but I really don't understand how you pass the validation.

Comment: this link may work for you [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8677985/primefaces-jsf-update-after-validation-failed-doesnt-work)