# Reset input fields without executing validation

Tags: jsf, primefaces, facelets, reset

I have a Facelets view as below:

```
<h:form id="f1">
<p:panelGrid id="p1" columns="2"> 
<p: inputText value="Distance Travelled::/><p:inputText value="#{airTransportUsage.distance}" immediate="true"
required="true" requiredMessage="Distance Travelled Field cannot be left blank.."
converterMessage="Distance Travelled must be a number"
validatorMessage="Distance Travelled must be a valid number.."
id="dis">
<f:validateLongRange minimum="1"/>
</p:inputText>
<p:commandButton value="Reset" action="#{airTransportUsage.reset}" update=":f1:p1" />
</p:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

When the reset button is clicked, the corresponding method can never be executed due to validation. I can't use `immediate="true"` on my reset button as it creates some other problems.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The `<p:commandButton>` processes indeed by default the entire form (`process="@form"`), you can change this by specifying only the current component in the `process` attribute.

```
<p:commandButton value="Reset" ... process="@this" />
```

However, this will fail if the form is already been validated beforehand. The input fields which have been marked invalid won't be updated with the new model value (which you've resetted yourself). If you're using PrimeFaces 3.4, then embed [`<p:resetInput>`](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/resetInput.xhtml) in the button:

```
<p:commandButton value="Reset" ... process="@this">
    <p:resetInput target="@form" />
</p:commandButton>
```

If you aren't on PrimeFaces 3.4 yet and can't upgrade to it, you can use OmniFaces [`ResetInputAjaxActionListener`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/eventlisteners/ResetInputAjaxActionListener) for this.

A completely different alternative is to just refresh the current page by a fresh new GET request.

```
<p:button value="Reset" />
```

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me in PrimeFaces 5.3

```html
<p:commandButton action="#{bean.reset()}" value="Reset" process="@this" update="@form" resetValues="true" />
```

You can probably replace the `"@form"` target of the update attribute to a specific component if you want.

Comment: this worked for me. I needed both the actionListener and the resetValues. thanks!