# How to reset input fields in a form after validation fail when updating it with new values

Tags: validation, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm using JSF 2 with PrimeFaces 4.0.

I have a form with some inputs and validation. Some fields may automatically filled when choosing an entity from a dialog. This works fine when I choose the entity before I submit the whole form (and validate). But when I choose an entity after validation the update of the component does not work.

JSF page:

```
<h:form id="form">
    <p:inputText id="id" value="#{bean.user.id}" required="true" 
        onclick="PF('usersDialog').show()" />
    <p:inputText id="name" value="#{bean.user.name}" required="true"
        onclick="PF('usersDialog').show()" />
    <p:commandButton value="submit" action="#{bean.submit}" update=":form" />
</h:form>

<p:dialog widgetVar="usersDialog">
    <h:form>
        <p:dataTable value="#{bean.users}" var="user">
            <p:column>
                <p:commandButton value="choose" onclick="PF('usersDialog').hide()"
                    process="@this" action="#{bean.select(user)}" update=":form" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <h:outputText value="#{user.name}" />
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
    </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

I know its up to the JSF lifecycle, but I'm not able to fix it.
So how can I update the form after validation fail when choosing an new entity from dialog?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your validation is probably being broken somewhere. It's advisable to have an `h:messages` tag at least to see what's going on. Another interesting tip is to have separate forms for both the panel and the dialog components.

Comment: The validation works with p:message. Seperating the forms does not solve the issue or?

Comment: It's better to have `p:messages` or `h:messages` indeed, to have the server messages displayed, in order not to bind to an only component.

Comment: Ok I added p:messages, but this does not solve the issue

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Exactly for this purpose, [`<p:resetInput>` component](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/resetInput.xhtml) was introduced (based on [OmniFaces `ResetInputAjaxActionListener`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/eventlisteners/ResetInputAjaxActionListener)).

Nest it inside the command button, with a `target` set to the same client ID as `update` attribute of command button:

```
<p:commandButton ... update=":form">
    <p:resetInput target=":form" />
</p:commandButton>
```

#### See also:

- [How can I populate a text field using PrimeFaces AJAX after validation errors occur?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6642242/how-can-i-populate-a-text-field-using-primefaces-ajax-after-validation-errors-oc/6845800#6845800)
- [Reset input fields without executing validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12619228/reset-input-fields-without-executing-validation/12619890#12619890)

Answer (score 0):

try this way:

```
<h:form id="form">
    <p:panel style="width: 80%;">
        <p:fieldset legend="Some User" id="costAuthUser">
            <p:panelGrid columns="3">
                <h:outputLabel for="costUserId">User-ID</h:outputLabel>
                <p:inputText id="costUserId" onclick="PF('costAuthDialog').show()"
                    value="#{createCert.costAuthUser.userId }" required="true"
                    requiredMessage="Bitte geben Sie die UserID ein." />
                <p:message for="costUserId" />

                <h:outputLabel for="costLastName">Name</h:outputLabel>
                <p:inputText id="costLastName"
                    onclick="PF('costAuthDialog').show()"
                    value="#{createCert.costAuthUser.lastName }" />
                <!-- <p:watermark value="" for="costLastName"/> -->
                <p:message for="costLastName" />
            </p:panelGrid>
        </p:fieldset>

        <p:separator />

        <p:commandButton value="submit" action="#{createCert.prepareEmail }" update=":form"/>

    </p:panel>
<h:form>


<p:dialog widgetVar="costAuthDialog" resizable="false" header="Some User">
    <h:form id="dialogForm">
        <p:dataTable value="#{createCert.costAuthList}" var="user">
            <p:column>
             <p:commandButton value="choose" process="@this"
                oncomplete="PF('costAuthDialog').hide()" action="#{createCert.selectCostAuth(user) }" update=":form"/>
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Name">
                <h:outputText value="#{user.lastName}" />
            </p:column>
            <!-- Some more -->
        </p:dataTable>
    </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

i think there's some issue re-rendering dialog hierarchies, this way dialog does not get updated.

and you should use `oncomplete="PF('costAuthDialog').hide()"` instead of `onclick`