# How to get p:resetInput functionality on p:ajax-submitted input component

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, reset

I have a text field and a validator as shown below.  It uses **p:ajax** to submit the value the moment it is changed, and the validator stops the submission if the field does not pass.   The user gets the error message as expected (which is what update="msgs .." does).

However when it doesn't pass I want to reset the value to what it was before.

```
                                <p:inputText id="txtName"
                                             value="#{workspace.selectedPath.name}"
                                             style="width: 20%"
                                             validator="validateName"
                                             valueChangeListener="#{workspace.doNameChanged}"
                                             >
                                    <p:ajax update="msgs formTree" />
                                </p:inputText>
```

The following link shows how to use the **p:resetInput** tag in PrimeFaces, but it doesn't work as part of **p:inputText** because it is not an ActionSource.  If you make it a child of the **p:ajax** tag it is just ignored.    Any suggestions?

[How to reset input fields in a form after validation fail when updating it with new values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21179403/how-to-reset-input-fields-in-a-form-after-validation-fail-when-updating-it-with)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since PrimeFaces 4.0, you can use [`<p:ajax resetValues>`](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/5.3/core/primefaces-p/ajax.html) for this.

```
<p:inputText ...>
    <p:ajax ... resetValues="true" />
</p:inputText>
```

#### See also:

- [How can I populate a text field using PrimeFaces AJAX after validation errors occur?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6642242/how-can-i-populate-a-text-field-using-primefaces-ajax-after-validation-errors-oc/)

Comment: Shoulda known you'd have this.