# No Update of Fields after Validation error

Tags: ajax, validation, user-interface, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a primefaces dialog in which I can create or update an Employee. 
It will open by this

```
    </p:dialog><p:dialog id="employeeEditDialog" header="#{msg.employeeEdit}"
        widgetVar="dlgEmployeeEdit" resizable="false">

        <p:ajax  event="close" listener="#{employeeView.cancel}"
              update=":showEmployees:liste" />

        <ui:include src="/content/Employee/ShowEmployeeContent.xhtml" />
    </p:dialog>
```

And here is the Dialog Page

```
<h:form id="editContent">
<p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" sticky="false" life="5000" />
<p:focus id="focusEdit" for="emSalutation" />
<h:panelGrid columns="2" id="contentGrid">
    <h:panelGrid columns="2" id="allgemein">                                                            <h:outputText value="#{msg.id}" />
        <h:outputText value="#{employeeView.newEmployee.id}" />

        <h:outputText value="#{msg.salutation}" />
        <p:selectOneMenu value="#{employeeView.newEmployee.salutation}"
            id="emSalutation">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="" itemValue="" />
            <f:selectItems value="#{employeeView.salutations}" var="salutations"
                itemLabel="#{salutations.description}" itemValue="#{salutations}" />
        </p:selectOneMenu>

        <h:outputText value="#{msg.title}" />
        <p:inputText value="#{employeeView.newEmployee.title}" id="emTitle" />

        <h:outputText value="#{msg.name}" />
        <p:inputText value="#{employeeView.newEmployee.name}" id="emName"
            validatorMessage="#{msg.valName}" />

        <h:outputText value="#{msg.prename}" />
        <p:inputText value="#{employeeView.newEmployee.prename}"
            id="emPrename" />

        <h:outputText value="#{msg.loginname}" />
        <p:inputText value="#{employeeView.newEmployee.loginname}"
            validatorMessage="#{msg.valLogin}" />

        <h:outputText value="#{msg.department}" />
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" id="departmentGrid">
            <p:selectOneMenu value="#{employeeView.selectedDepartment.id}"
                id="emDepartment">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="" itemValue="" />
                <f:selectItems value="#{employeeView.departmentList}"
                    var="department" itemLabel="#{department.description}"
                    itemValue="#{department.id}" />
            </p:selectOneMenu>
            <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-disk" immediate="true"
                oncomplete="dlgDepartmentAdd.show()"
                update="departmentGrid, :departmentAddDialog">
            </p:commandButton>
        </h:panelGrid>

        <h:outputText value="#{msg.position}" />
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" id="positionGrid">
            <p:selectOneMenu value="#{employeeView.selectedPosition.id}"
                id="emPosition">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="" itemValue="" />
                <f:selectItems value="#{employeeView.positionList}" var="position"
                    itemLabel="#{position.description}" itemValue="#{position.id}" />
            </p:selectOneMenu>
            <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-disk" immediate="true" id="buttonPos"
                oncomplete="dlgPositionAdd.show()"
                update="positionGrid, :positionAddDialog">
            </p:commandButton>
        </h:panelGrid>

        <h:outputText value="#{msg.phone}" />
        <p:inputText value="#{employeeView.newEmployee.phone}" id="emPhone" />

        <h:outputText value="#{msg.fax}" />
        <p:inputText value="#{employeeView.newEmployee.fax}" id="emFax" />

        <h:outputText value="#{msg.email}" />
        <p:inputText value="#{employeeView.newEmployee.email}" id="emEmail"
            validator="myEmailValidator" validatorMessage="#{msg.valEmail}" />

        <h:outputText value="#{msg.employeedSince}" />
        <p:calendar value="#{employeeView.newEmployee.employeedSince}"
            id="emEmployeedSince" pattern="dd.MM.yyy" showOn="button" />

        <h:outputText value="#{msg.employeedEnd}" />
        <p:calendar value="#{employeeView.newEmployee.employeedEnd}"
            id="emEmployeedEnd" pattern="dd.MM.yyy" showOn="button" />

        <h:outputText value="#{msg.active}" />
        <p:selectBooleanCheckbox  value="#{employeeView.newEmployee.active}"
            id="emActive" /> 
    </h:panelGrid>

</h:panelGrid>

<h:panelGrid columns="3" class="buttonContent" id="button">
    <p:commandButton value="#{msg.save}" id="saveButton" update="growl"
        oncomplete="if ((!args.validationFailed)) dlgEmployeeEdit.hide()"
        actionListener="#{employeeView.saveOrUpdateEmployee}" />
    <p:commandButton value="#{msg.cancel}" immediate="true"
        oncomplete="dlgEmployeeEdit.hide()"/>
    <p:commandButton value="#{msg.delete}" immediate="true"
        oncomplete="dlgEmployeeDelete.show()"
        disabled="#{(employeeView.newEmployee.id == null) ? true : false}" />
</h:panelGrid>

<p:defaultCommand target="saveButton" /></h:form></html>
```

And now here are the two Methods which used in the Page:

```
/**
 * Methode zum Speichern und Updaten eines Mitarbeiters
 */
public void saveOrUpdateEmployee() {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    try {
        logger.debug("save aufgerufen " + this.newEmployee);
        if (this.selectedDepartment.getId() == null) {
            this.newEmployee.setDepartment(null);
        }
        else {
            this.newEmployee.setDepartment(this.departmentHandler.getDepartmentById(this.selectedDepartment.getId()));
        }
        if (this.selectedPosition.getId() == null) {
            this.newEmployee.setPosition(null);
        }
        else {
            this.newEmployee.setPosition(this.positionHandler.getPositionById(this.selectedPosition.getId()));
        }
        this.employeeController.saveOrUpdate(this.newEmployee);
        logger.info("Mitarbeiter erfolgreich gespeichert");
        context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Successful", "Mitarbeiter gespeichert "));
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Fehler beim Speichern des Mitarbeiters", e);
        context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Fehler beim Speichern des Mitarbeiters", e.getMessage()));
    }
    this.loadPersons();
}

/**
 * Methode zum Abbrechen bei der Neuanlage/Änderung eines Mitarbeiters
 * Felder leeren
 */
public void cancel() {
    logger.debug("cancel()");
    this.newEmployee = new Employee();
    this.selected = new Employee();
    this.selectedDepartment = new Department();
    this.selectedPosition = new Position();
}
```

If now, validation failed, the dialog will not hide. This is OK and desired. It shows my created message via FacesMassages as required. If I then close the dialogbox by myself with the "cancel"-Button, dialog will close as expected. In the cancel()-method the object Employee will be set to a new instance of Employee (`this.newEmployee = new Employee()`) as you can see. But when I open the dialog after validation failure, the object "newEmployee" contains just the old values... Why does my method cancel()not work? I don't understand.

Comment: Hey BalusC!I have to correct my answer!It works!I have just forgot to register the ResetInputAjaxActionListener as phase-listener!THanks for your help and fast answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem is related to [JSF issue 1060](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES_SPEC_PUBLIC-1060) and in detail elaborated in this Q&A: [How can I populate a text field using PrimeFaces AJAX after validation errors occur?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6642242/how-can-i-populate-a-text-field-using-primefaces-ajax-after-validation-errors-oc/6845800#6845800)

To the point, this behaviour is (unfortunately) correct as per current JSF specification and this can be solved as follows: during the invoke action phase you need to collect `UIInput` components which are included in the ajax render, but not in the ajax execute, and then invoke [`resetValue()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIInput.html#resetValue%28%29) method on them. This can be in a generic and reuseable fashion be done with help of [OmniFaces `ResetInputAjaxActionListener`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/eventlisteners/ResetInputAjaxActionListener).

Comment: Your solution have helped me but it does not work all.Open the dialog by pressing button like this:
    <p:commandButton value="#{msg.employeeAdd}" id="addButton"
     update=":employeeEditDialog, :showEmployees, :editContent"
     oncomplete="dlgEmployeeEdit.show()">
    </p:commandButton>
With Dblclick in DataTable I can load and edit existing employees:
<p:ajax event="rowDblselect"  listener="#{employeeView.onRowSelect}" process="@this"
     update=":employeeEditDialog, :showEmployees, :editContent" oncomplete="dlgEmployeeEdit.show()" />
By dblclick after valFailed fields will not clear