# prime faces after submit ajax doesn't update

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

Using PF 3.2 
I faced this problem
if I submit a form and their is a required field, validation done and required messages appeared. the problem is after that if I changed the combo value that -by ajax- changes the inputtext the value doesn't change, however the listener called!
**xhtml**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<h:head>
    <title>Prime Test</title>
</h:head>


<h:body style="background: #F6F6F6;">
    <h:form id="idAjaxFormTest">
        <f:view>
           <h1> <h:outputText value="after submit ajax problem" /></h1>
            <p:messages showSummary="true" autoUpdate="true" />
            <p:panelGrid columns="2">
                <h:outputText value="Names" />
                <p:selectOneMenu value="#{ajaxTest.name}">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{ajaxTest.names}" var="varName"
                                   itemLabel="#{varName}" itemValue="#{varName}">
                    </f:selectItems>
                    <p:ajax listener="#{ajaxTest.listen}" update="idXname" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>

                <h:outputText value="Xname" />
                <p:inputText value="#{ajaxTest.xname}" id="idXname"/>

                <h:outputText value="Xuser" />
                <p:inputText required="true" transient="true" value="#{ajaxTest.xuser}" label="xUser" />
            </p:panelGrid>
            <p:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{ajaxTest.doAction}" />
        </f:view>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

**Bean**

```
package com.actions;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;


@ManagedBean(name = "ajaxTest")
@ViewScoped

public class AjaxTestBean implements Serializable{
    private List<String> names;
    private String name;
    private String xname;
    private String xuser;

public AjaxTestBean() {
    names = new ArrayList<String>();
    names.add("ahmed");
    names.add("mohamed");
    names.add("mahmoud");
    names.add("ayman");
    names.add("walid");
    names.add("khalid");
}

public void listen(){
    xname = "QQ "+ name;
    System.out.println("Listener "+ xname);
}
public void doAction(){
    System.out.println("Action Done: "+ name);
}

public List<String> getNames() {
    return names;
}

public void setNames(List<String> names) {
    this.names = names;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getXname() {
    return xname;
}

public void setXname(String xname) {
    this.xname = xname;
}

public String getXuser() {
    return xuser;
}

public void setXuser(String xuser) {
    this.xuser = xuser;
}


}
```

[image: action01]

[image: action02]

Comment: nice exampe. very easy to understand a recreate problem. you propably need to reset the validationstatus of the form somehow. primefaces has some components for reset, but i havnt played around with them enough to answer your question.

Comment: Your examples run fine (copy-paste, no edits) here in my environment, however I am using primefaces 3.3.1 Maybe updating your primefaces version can fix it.

Comment: open the console or firebug, see if the page is making the ajax calls after the submit.

Comment: can you tel me the Mojarra version?

Comment: from firebug it made a partial response

Comment: i think this is the part of xml that made this   <update id="idAjaxFormTest:idXname"><input id="idAjaxFormTest:idXname" name="idAjaxFormTest:idXname" type="text" value="QQ ayman" class="ui-inputfield ui-inputtext ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" /><script id="idAjaxFormTest:idXname_s" type="text/javascript">PrimeFaces.cw('InputText','widget_idAjaxFormTest_idXname',{id:'idAjaxFormTest:idXname'});</script></update>

Comment: another note if i changed the   `<p:inputText value="#{ajaxTest.xname}" id="idXname"/>` to `<h:inputText value="#{ajaxTest.xname}" id="idXname"/>` it will be affected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you have run into this problem:

[How can I populate a text field using PrimeFaces AJAX after validation errors occur?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6642242/how-can-i-populate-a-text-field-using-primefaces-ajax-after-validation-errors-oc/6845800#6845800)

Adding the following to faces-config.xml together with OmniFaces library made your select-one-menu update the inputField correctly

```
<lifecycle>
    <phase-listener>org.omnifaces.eventlistener.ResetInputAjaxActionListener</phase-listener>
</lifecycle>
```

If you dont want to do it for all your components, OmniFaces has a showcase how to do it per component: http://showcase.omnifaces.org/eventlisteners/ResetInputAjaxActionListener