# h:inputText not updating from bean automatically

Tags: jsf

I have an h:inputText in my form. The value is not properly updating when I update its panelGroup. JSF version is 2.1.13.

If I used disable="true"  OR displaying the bean value in h:outputText OR refresh the page its updating properly. But by default its not happening.

```
<span style="min-width: 100px;"> First Name: #{NewPatient.newPatientBean.firstName}</span>
                <h:inputText id="fname" 
                    value="#{NewPatient.newPatientBean.firstName}"
                    onchange="initialCaps(this);" maxlength="50">
                    <f:ajax execute="@this" event="blur"/>
                </h:inputText>
```

In the above code

> First Name: #{NewPatient.newPatientBean.firstName} is properly updating but the inputText is not.

Kindly let me know the mistake and solution for the above issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you update the panelGroup? Where's the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That will happen when a validation error occurred during the current or previous postbacks. The input component will then not redisplay the model value, but only the initially submitted value when the component itself failed validation or the local value when another component in the same form failed validation.

As the concrete functional requirement is completely absent in the question, it's not possible to propose the right solution for this. So here's just a link which explains the problem more generically which should give new insights as to the cause and the solution: [How can I populate a text field using PrimeFaces AJAX after validation errors occur?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6642242/how-can-i-populate-a-text-field-using-primefaces-ajax-after-validation-errors-oc/6845800#6845800)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. The issue gets fixed.