# p:outputLabel would not update

Tags: jsf, label, updates

I have a dialog box containing p:inputText with required="true" and a corresponding p:outputLabel.

```
<p:outputLabel for="name"   value="First Name" />
<p:inputText id="name"  value="#{userManagedBean.name}" required="true"/>
```

I submit the dialog box without any value causing a validation error indicated by the p:outputLabel in red required mark. But on **reopening the dialog without submitting**, the  outputLabel is still in the invalidate state(red font). It doesnt get updated until I submit or navigate back from other page. I tried to update the whole dialog box but it wouldnt affect the label.

Thanks in advance

Comment: _"reopening the dialog without submitting"_, how so ?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6642242/how-can-i-populate-a-text-field-using-primefaces-ajax-after-validation-errors-oc/6845800#6845800

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behaviour as input components (and related components) will maintain their state after validation fails. The state is only changed after the full request is re-executed and the complete JSF lifecycle is executed again.

You're not stating exactly *how* you're "updating" the panel, but I can recommend [`<p:resetInput/>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/resetInput.jsf) to explicitly reset the state of related input components, without having to resubmit the entire `<h:form/>`. If you'd posted more meaningful code, I might have been able to give a working snippet

Comment: Working now, but in commandLink submit I am having to give "ajax=false", can this be avoided?

Comment: @user1782556 - yes it can be avoided, using `<p:resetInput/>`

Comment: yes I have used <p:resetInput/> for it to work, but the submit commandLink only being ajax="false", i want it to work on ajax="true" on submit

Comment: @user1782556 You need to post more code showing how you're using the component and the reset target. Probably something to do with your `update` attribute on the reset trigger or some other ajax issue in your setup

Answer (score -1):

It will not be updated since opening the dialog box is happening in javascript (client side).

You need to re-render your dialog box when you open it.

Comment: Sorry im basic in JSF, how to re-render?

Comment: If you are using a command link to open the dialog add the id of the dialog box/ component to the "render" attribute
EX:
<h:commandButton>
    <f:ajax execute="@this" render="id-of-dialog-box" />
</h:commandButton>