# h:inputText and h:outputText show different values for same (EL) field

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, richfaces

I've got a very strange problem here. I have a rich:popupModal which is used to edit an entity. Some of the input fields on that modal use a validator. There is also some ajax going on which is used to update other fields on that modal. There is e.g. a 'Number of packages' field, a weight per package field and a total weight field. If you change the number of packages it will update the total weight field, etc.

Now when e.g. the user entered a value that is too high, the validation fails, an error message is shown. The user can either correct the values on the modal or press cancel.

When he cancels the entity is reset to the values it had before the edit (there were some ajax changes so I need to reset those). The modal closes and a table is showing the correct (reset) values for that entity.

Now the strange thing happens. When I edit another entity the modal is suddenly showing the old values for the previous entity (the ones that did not pass validation).
To debug this I was checking whether the correct instance of the commodity is used so I added h:outputText fields for some of the values and I am also showing the System hash of the entity on the modal. 
I've got e.g. 
`<h:outputText value="#{backingBean.entity.description}"/>` which prints 'Stuff 1'
and then 
`<h:inputText value="#{backingBean.entity.description}"/>` which prints 'Stuff 3' (the first entity I've edited). WTH?
I've added getter and a dummy setter on the entity to return the System.identityHashCode. And h:outputText and h:inputText use indeed a different entity but how is that possible when  the EL is `#{backingBean.entity.hashId}` in both cases?

I've used the richfaces a:log to see whether that shows any errors but it all looks okay.
I have tried to clear the modal on cancel (rerender it with no components in) but that didn't fix the problem either. I've tried it on both Chrome and Firefox. Both have the same problem.

What could be going on here?

My environment: JSF 2, Seam 2.3, RichFaces 4.3.3, JBoss EAP 6.1

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I populate a text field using primefaces ajax after validation errors occur?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6642242/how-can-i-populate-a-text-field-using-primefaces-ajax-after-validation-errors-oc)

Comment: Yes I agree, I also found your blog on it. I would like to use OmniFaces but it doesn't seem to work with Seam 2.3 unfortunately.

Comment: It would be great if you could provide a minimalistic WAR (without RichFaces) with a specific testcase demonstrating the problem with this combination, so that I can investigate how it's caused and eventually fix it.

Comment: Sorry very busy at the moment, so not sure whether I will be able to but you could use seam-gen to create a little dummy project or just use some of the seam examples and put Omnifaces inside.