# Clear input validation error from backing bean

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a dataTable with cell editor. And I want to only have some (selected) rows editable. And when the user uses the cell editor, I want to perform input validation immediately after the value is set.

So I use cellEdit event in the data table and from the event handler I trigger validation failure.

```
<p:ajax event="cellEdit" listener="#{bean.onEditCell}" update=":formId:propertySelect" />
```

This works like a charm. If the user enters an invalid value, the editor doesn't close and the error message is displayed.

What doesn't work is the user inputting a valid value afterwards. The cellEdit event does not trigger again since the form is in "input validation failure state".

I have lost a day trying to resolve that:

- I want to reset input validation when a user sets a new value - resetInput only works from buttons. I couldn't get it working on value change.
- I didn't find how to reset the field from JavaScript directly.
- if I combine "onchange" event and "remoteCommand" a handler is called in the backing bean, but then I cannot find the UIInput to call resetValue() on it.

  ```
  <p:dataTable id="propertySelect" value="#{bean.propertyValues}" var="prop" 
      editable="true" editMode="cell" scrollable="true" 
      scrollHeight="200" widgetVar="propSelectTable" 
      filteredValue="#{bean.filteredPVs}">
  <p:ajax event="cellEdit" listener="#{bean.onEditCell}" update=":#{formId}:propertySelect" />
  <p:ajax event="filter" oncomplete="updateToggle()" />

  <p:column id="rowSelection">
      <f:facet name="header">
          <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="toggleAll" value="#{bean.selectAllRows}">
              <p:ajax listener="#{bean.handleToggleAll}" update=":#{formId}:propertySelect" />
          </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
      </f:facet>
      <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{prop.selected}">
          <p:ajax update=":#{formId}:propertySelect" oncomplete="updateToggle()" listener="#{bean.rowSelectListener(prop)}"/>
      </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
  </p:column>
  <p:column headerText="Property">
      <h:outputText value="#{prop.name}" />
  </p:column>
  <p:column headerText="Description">
      <h:outputText value="#{prop.description}" />
  </p:column>
  <p:column headerText="Value">
      <p:cellEditor rendered="#{prop.selected}">
          <f:facet name="output">
              <h:outputText value="#{bean.displayPV(prop)}" />
          </f:facet>
          <f:facet name="input">
              <p:inputText id="pvSimple" value="#{prop.uiValue}" rendered="#{prop.propertyValueUIElement eq 'INPUT'}" />
              <p:inputTextarea id="pvArea" rows="7" value="#{prop.uiValue}" 
                  rendered="#{prop.propertyValueUIElement eq 'TEXT_AREA'}" />
              <p:selectOneMenu id="pvEnum" value="#{prop.uiValue}" 
                      rendered="#{prop.propertyValueUIElement eq 'SELECT_ONE_MENU'}">
                  <f:selectItem itemLabel="&lt;Select value&gt;" itemValue="" />        
                  <f:selectItems value="#{prop.enumOptions}" var="enum" itemLabel="#{enum}" itemValue="#{enum}" />        
              </p:selectOneMenu>
          </f:facet>
      </p:cellEditor>
      <h:outputText value="-" rendered="#{!prop.selected}" />
  </p:column>
  ```

I am looking for a way to clear input validation errors on the input fields with the ids "pvSimple", "pvArea" or "pvEnum".

Comment: I haven't tried it, but `<p:ajax>` has a `resetValues` attribute which should theoretically work (the same way as you intented to use `<p:resetInput>`). See also a.o. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6642242/how-can-i-populate-a-text-field-using-primefaces-ajax-after-validation-errors-oc

Comment: @BalusC: Thanks, I was aware of that, but I didn't find a way to combine all that into a working solution. The desired functionality being: _if_ there is an input validation failure on the input component **AND** the user entered a new value, the field should have the validation failure cleared and the new value should be validated.

Comment: Actually I just discovered that it works, with one exception:
I was testing on the selectOneMenu, and before the validation error changing the value also triggers the _editing done_ action. **After** the validation error, the user has to specifically press _Enter_ even on the dropdown menu.