# JSF incorrectly retains old values in form after validation failure

Tags: ajax, primefaces, jsf-2.2

My question is somewhat similar to this one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6642242).

I have a form `Parent` with a few `commandButton`s one for each of the several entries on the page/form. When I click on the `commandButton` `C1` for an entry, say, `E1`, a new form, `Child` pops up with some fields on it populated thru an AJAX call.

If I cause a validation error on this form `Child` by, say, submitting the form with some required fields missing, I get the validation error back, which is all good.

Now, when I exit the pop-up, get back on the form `Parent` and click the `commandButton` `C2` of a different entry `E2`, the form in the popup, `Child`, contains the details of that of the `E1`, despite the ajax call on the click of the `commandButton` `C2` to load the information corresponding to the entry `E2`. In fact, opening any entry from the `Parent` after that always displays the details of the entry `E1` in the popup's form: `Child` until I actually refresh/reload the page.

Using the `resetValues="true"` on the `commandButton`s doesn't seem to have any impact. Any suggestion?

Comment: To exclude one and other, does a nested `<p:resetInput target=":dialogId">` work?

Comment: @BalusC Perfect, that works!  And thinking about it, it does make sense to reset the elements in the dialog, given by `dialogId`! I'll accept this answer once you add it as one.

Comment: I only wonder why `resetValues="true"` didn't work then. Which PF version?

Comment: @BalusC Primefaces v5.1. I must admit I haven't read the exact working of `resetValues`, but `resetInput` as a separate nested element with a target component sounds sensible to me.  What values exactly are attempted for a reset with `resetValues="true"` (with a nested `resetInput` with a `target`, this is obvious)?

Comment: It will reset anything specified in `update`. So this problem can happen if you don't have `update=":dialogId"`, but that would in turn be strange as that conflicts your intent (showing detail of current item in dialog).