# What is the role of resetValues attribute of <f:ajax> in JSF2.2?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2, reset, ajax-update

I have gone through the [JSF 2.2 docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/toc.htm), which mentions for this particular attribute,

> If true, indicate that this particular Ajax transaction is a value
>   reset transaction. This will cause resetValue() to be called on any
>   EditableValueHolder instances encountered as a result of this ajax
>   transaction. If not specified, or the value is false, no such
>   indication is made.

What does the author meant by `value reset transaction`?
I am unable to understand what basic functionality does it offers & when should it be used?

Please elaborate?

An example explaining it in below context would indeed be very helpful,

```
<h:inputText id="nameId" value="#{ajaxBean.name}" />
<h:commandButton value="Submit">
                <f:ajax onevent="ajaxMonitoring" 
                        execute="@form" 
                        resetValues="true" 
                        listener="#{ajaxBean.listener()}" 
                        render="@form"/>
</h:commandButton>
```

Comment: Trigger was this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6642242