# Incorrect view update after validation error

Tags: jsf, primefaces

View looks like this:

`form` (can have only one checkbox selected)

## ----------------------------------------

`checkbox_1` (on value change clears `checkbox_1` and `checkbox_2` values in the backing bean and updates `form**. new` checkbox_1`value is set after all checkbox values are cleared)`row_checkbox_1`(rendered only if`checkbox_1` is checked)

`checkbox_2` (on value change clears `checkbox_1` and `checkbox_2` values in the backing bean and updates `form**. new` checkbox_2`value is set after all checkbox values are cleared)`row_checkbox_2`(rendered only if`checkbox_2` is checked)

`saveButton` (on click updates `form`and a separate `messages` component)

## ---------------------------------

Lets state `checkbox_1` is selected meaning that `row_checkbox_1` components is also visible. Also there are errors in `row_checkbox_1` fields.
After `saveButton`is pressed the errors are displayed.
**Problem**: pressing/checking `checkbox_2` updates backing bean - `checkbox_1` value field in the backing bean gets set to false (debugged and verified by looking at getter) and `checkbox_2` value field is set to true. However view does not update correctly since `checkbox_1` is *rendered as checked* while `row_checkbox_1` is *not rendered* at all. Remember `row_checkbox_1` is rendered only if `checkbox_1` is true. `checkbox_2` is rendered and checked as it should be and `row_checkbox_2` fields are visible as it should be.

I'm doing all this in PrimeFaces 6.0

Comment: Version info does not belong in the title UNLESS it e.g. works with a previous version and is a regression. Still than, see ; https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ajax attribute `restValues="true"` helped. Maybe someone could do an explanation why this situation occurs? Would gladly give answer point to them!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6642242/how-can-i-populate-a-text-field-using-primefaces-ajax-after-validation-errors-oc